# What is the probability that the chosen day is a weekday?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

The number of emails that I get in a weekday (Monday through Friday) can be modeled by a Poisson distribution with an average of 1/6 emails per minute. The number of emails that I receive on weekends (Saturday and Sunday) can be modeled by a Poisson distribution with an average of 1/30 emails per minute

A random day is chosen (all days of the week are equally likely to be selected), and a random interval of length one hour is selected in the chosen day. It is observed that I did not receive any emails in that interval. What is the probability that the chosen day is a weekday?

Comment: any thoughts? can you find the probability of not getting any emails for an hour, if you know what day it is?

Comment: Hey, the probability of not getting any emails for an hour on Sunday or Saturday is 0.135 while the probability of not getting any emails for an hour on weekdays are 0.00005

Comment: so now it's just a conditional probability problem; without the condition, it's 2/7 for weekend and 5/7 for weekday; draw a tree diagram and work out the conditional probability

Comment: and use more significant figures for the weekday, this 0.00005 is not precise enough

Comment: So to write it down I can say that A is the event that I’m not getting any emails for an hour. and T the days in the weekend (2/7) and D the weekdays (5/7) so $P(A \mid D) = e^-10$ and $P(A \mid T) = e^-2$ right ? Then I think would like to find the $P(D \mid A) = ((e^-10 * (5/7))) / e^-10 + e^-2$ but is that right ?

Comment: in principle, yes, I think the last expression is not quite right, you are missing some 5/7 and 2/7 factors in the denominator

Comment: @NickPavlov how? I’m not following you?

Comment: $ P(D|A) = \frac{P(D \cap A)}{P(A)} = \frac{P(D)P(A|D)}{P(D)P(A|D) + P(T)P(A|T)} $

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks 

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ represent the number of emails you receive in an hour on a weekday and let $Y$ represent the number of emails you receive in an hour on a weekend. Let $Z$ be the random variable representing how many emails you received in an hour knowing that the day you selected could be any day of the week.

$$X\sim\mathrm{Po}(10)\implies\operatorname{P}(X=x)=\frac{10^x}{e^{10}x!}\tag{1}$$
$$Y\sim\mathrm{Po}(2)\implies\operatorname{P}(Y=y)=\frac{2^y}{e^{2}y!}\tag{2}$$

Bayes’ theorem tells us

$$\operatorname{P}(B \,|\, A) = \frac{ \operatorname{P}(B) \, \operatorname{P}(A \,|\, B) }{\operatorname{P}(B) \, \operatorname{P}(A \,|\, B) + \operatorname{P}\left(B'\right) \, \operatorname{P}\left(A \,\middle|\, B'\right)}$$

Taking $B$ to be the event $D$ and $A$ to be the event $Z=0$, we have

$$\operatorname{P}(D \,|\, Z=0) = \frac{ \operatorname{P}(D) \, \operatorname{P}(Z=0 \,|\, D) }{\operatorname{P}(D) \, \operatorname{P}(Z=0 \,|\, D) + \operatorname{P}\left(D'\right) \, \operatorname{P}\left(Z=0 \,\middle|\, D'\right)}$$

Given if $D$ occurs, $Z=0$ can actually be more precisely written as $X=0$; if $D'$ occurs, then $Z=0$ can actually be more precisely written as $Y=0$, giving you

$$\operatorname{P}(D \,|\, Z=0) = \frac{ \operatorname{P}(D) \, \operatorname{P}(X=0 \,|\, D) }{\operatorname{P}(D) \, \operatorname{P}(X=0 \,|\, D) + \operatorname{P}\left(D'\right) \, \operatorname{P}\left(Y=0 \,\middle|\, D'\right)}$$

By the definition of our variables, we can further contract this to

$$\operatorname{P}(D \,|\, Z=0) = \frac{ \operatorname{P}(D) \, \operatorname{P}(X=0) }{\operatorname{P}(D) \, \operatorname{P}(X=0) + \operatorname{P}\left(D'\right) \, \operatorname{P}(Y=0)}$$

because if we’re analyzing $X$, we know we’re looking at a weekday, and if we’re analyzing $Y$, we know we’re looking at a weekend.

Use $(1)$ and $(2)$ in conjunction with $\operatorname{P}(D)=5/7$ and $\operatorname{P}\left(D'\right)=2/7$ to arrive at your answer.